# How do I get the module handle of the satellite resource DLL? (c++ visual studio )

Tags: c++, string, resources

We have moved all our strings to resources (and satellite DLLs) for an MFC application.  Right now the primary language is incorporated into the EXE itself so when I call LoadString() I can just pass in the module handle of the exe.

However, I need to make this generic - how do I get the module handle in a generic way and make sure I load strings form a satellite DLL if appropriate?  We need to get the appropriate module for the currently loaded resource DLL. (or the exe if English)

The ::LoadString() method takes a handle as its first argument - and we're just using the current exe's handle.

Do I have to determine if I need to load the DLL, or does Windows automatically do that for me.  It is not clear from the docs I have read.

[This indicates that MFC does it automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fkteez0%28vs.71%29.aspx).
 SO how do I get that hmodule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you've loaded the resources dll with `LoadLibrary`, you store its `HMODULE` (returned by `LoadLibrary`) and pass it to the `LoadString` function (as well as to the other resource functions).

By the way, if you use your resources DLLs exclusively to store resources (i.e. no code is included in them) you can load them with `LoadLibraryEx` with the `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` option, making the loading a bit faster and avoiding possible exploits due to malicious code embedded in resources dlls (but in this case [be careful with dialogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/10/05/477802.aspx)).

Comment: I thought that the exe automatically loaded the satellite DLLs based on the locale?

Comment: AFAIK the automatic language choice is when you have the same resource for multiple languages in the same module.

Comment: THis is what is causing my confusion:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fkteez0%28vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Tim: that's MFC-specific stuff, Win32 does not provide automatically anything like that.

Comment: @Tim: then you should have added the MFC tag, and I wouldn't have replied since I know nothing about MFC. `:)`

Comment: I was wrong anyway - we use MFC classes, but it is not an MFC app.  I was confused because I was reading what I thought were conflicting ideas - manual loading or automagic loading.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading the libray with LoadLibrary(Ex)? Remember the handle it returns.

Otherwise use GetModuleHandle("Name of resource module").

Comment: No - I am not loading the dll myself - I thought I read that the "correct" satellite dll gets loaded automatically by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Use [AfxGetResourceHandle().](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaewt3xs%28VS.80%29.aspx)